# Can't save a form in Django (object has no attribute 'save')

Tags: django, django-forms

The following is my form:

```
class AdvancedSearchForm(forms.Form):
    valueofres = forms.ChoiceField (label="res", choices = ((0, 0),(2.2, 2.2)), required= False)
```

The following is my view:

```py
def advancedsearch(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search = AdvancedSearchForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if search.is_valid():
            new_search = search.save(commit=False)
```

Why I'm getting the error `'AdvancedSearchForm' object has no attribute 'save'`?

Comment: `save` is available only for `ModelForm` by default., and not for `forms.Form`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`save` is available only for `ModelForm` by default, and not for `forms.Form`

What you need to do is this. Either use:

```py
class AdvancedSearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    valueofres = forms.ChoiceField (label="res", choices = ((0, 0),(2.2, 2.2)), required= False)
    class Meta:
        model=Search #or whatever object
```

Or:

```py
def advancedsearch(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_form = AdvancedSearchForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if search_form.is_valid():
            cd = search_form.cleaned_data
            search = #populate SearchObject()
            search.save()
```

Comment: In option 1 you need to use a `forms.ModelForm`

Answer (score 9):

`Form`s don't have a `save()` method.

You need to use a `ModelForm` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)) as that will then have a `model` associated with it and will know what to save where.

Alternatively you can keep your `forms.Form` but you'll want to then extract the valid data from the for and do as you will with eh data.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    search_form = AdvancedSearchForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if search_form.is_valid():
        cd = search_form.cleaned_data

        search = Search(
            # Apply form data
        )
        search.save()
```